# Is it possible to reset integers and strings with one button?

Tags: java, android, button

I am an android beginner. I want to create a reset button `resetTheGame` for my beach volleyball score counter app. The button should do following things:

- set current score of team A and team B to 0
- delete saved scores of the first, second and third set (strings)
- set the current set to 1

My idea was to do this:

```
  /**
 * This method is called when the save score button after first, second and third set is clicked.
 */

public void saveSetScore(View view) {

    if(currentSet == 1) {
        String firstSetMessage = "1st Set " + scoreTeamA + " Team A | " + scoreTeamB + " Team B";
        displayMessage(firstSetMessage);
    }

    else if(currentSet == 2) {
        String secondSetMessage = "2nd Set " + scoreTeamA + " Team A | " + scoreTeamB + " Team B";
        displayMessage(secondSetMessage);
    }

    else if(currentSet == 3) {
        String thirdSetMessage = "3rd Set " + scoreTeamA + " Team A | " + scoreTeamB + " Team B";
        displayMessage(thirdSetMessage);
    }


}


/**
 * resets the set score of Team A and B to 0
 */
public void resetTheSet(View view) {

    scoreTeamA = 0;
    scoreTeamB = 0;
    displayForTeamA(scoreTeamA);
    displayForTeamB(scoreTeamB);

    currentSet = (currentSet + 1);

}

public void resetTheGame(View view) {

    scoreTeamA = 0;
    scoreTeamB = 0;
    displayForTeamA(scoreTeamA);
    displayForTeamB(scoreTeamB);

    String firstSetMessage = "1st Set";
    displayMessage(firstSetMessage);
    String secondSetMessage = "2nd Set";
    displayMessage(secondSetMessage);
    String thirdSetMessage = "3rd Set";
    displayMessage(thirdSetMessage);

    currentSet = 1;
}
```

this code sets the current score of team A and B to 0, it sets the current set to 1 but it deletes only the last game set (string) and ignores the first and the second game set (strings). Is there any solution to fix it?

Comment: Could you give us more details? Who is `last game set` and `second game set`?

Comment: Please share more about the `displayMessage` method.

Comment: @FlorescuCătălin The score counter app consists of the score counter for team A and Team B 

**Team A 0
Team B 0**

and also of 3 sets (text view) that can be updated (via strings) with the final score of each set:

**1st Set 0 Team A | 0 Team B
2nd Set 0 Team A | 0 Team B
3rd Set 0 Team A | 0 Team B**

please let me know if you need a screenshot of the app

Comment: @bwicks I updated the code

Answer (score 0):

```
String firstSetMessage = "1st Set";
displayMessage(firstSetMessage);
String secondSetMessage = "2nd Set";
displayMessage(secondSetMessage);
String thirdSetMessage = "3rd Set";
displayMessage(thirdSetMessage);
```

The above code in your snippet is indeed setting the `firstSetMessage`, `secondSetMessage` and `thirdSetMessage` to the values you have assigned.

However, your method, `displayMessage()` is being called 3 times over. I would assume that from the little code you have given us to work with, your `displayMessage()` method simply creates a `Dialog`, or something similar.

Let's say for example that `displayMessage()` does create a `Dialog` then that means it's trying to open 3 dialogs at the same time, so will open the last one listed in your code as the code is read from the top to the bottom. (Of course with exceptions but that's for you to learn later down the line with the development of your android knowledge)

So overall, you would ideally present 3 messages all at once (or at least one after another) using a `Toast` which will display them one after another.